# RESTful Web Service in genymotion

Tags: android, web-services, genymotion

I created a restful web service in NetBeans using GlassFish Server and could run it through browsers(Firefox). URL that I type in browser is

http://localhost:8080/PlayerServer/webresources/com.playerentity.player/count

and the result that I got is "3", which is the number of people in database connected to my web service.
I also created an android client application to get information from my web service. I know that localhost refers to android emulator and since I used Genymotion I change above URL with below:

http://10.0.2.3:8080/PlayerServer/webresources/com.playerentity.player/count

but the result I got from genymotion is an exception with message:

```
failed to connect to /10.0.2.3(port 8080) connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

should I do anything before using the URL in the android emulator? for example copying the files of web service anywhere? if yes, which files?

Comment: Are you sure about `10.0.2.3`? IIRC it should be `10.0.3.2` -> note `2` and `3` have swapped places.

Comment: According to developer.android.com it should be 10.0.2.3, but when I try 10.0.3.2 it works! Right now I've got 406 Error! Do you know why? shouldn't I do anythings before testing web service in android?

Comment: 406 error solved! so problem solved! Thank you very very much for your response. Do you know why your answer works? because again accroding to http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.htm we need use 10.0.2.3

Comment: Genymotion runs on top of VirtualBox, whereas the standard Android Emulator doesn't. Not sure where the `10.0.3.2` is actually configured, but you'll find it's commonly referred to if you do a search. You can actually also use your host machine's VirtualBox IP address by the way: run `ifconfig` and look for the address mentioned with `vboxnet0` or `vboxnet1` or so. It's probably something like `192.168.56.1` or `192.168.57.1`.